# Helper data not found

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, helper, system.xml

I've this error when I access to any pages of my website

> Fatal error: Class 'IBP_SocialLinks_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ibp/app/Mage.php on line 547

I searched on many stack post but I not found the solution, can you help me please ?

So, this appears by the creation of a new system/general menu in my IBP/SocialLinks/etc/system.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <ibp_sociallinks_config translate="label" module="ibp_sociallinks">
            <label>Social links</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
        </ibp_sociallinks_config>
    </sections>
</config>
```

So here is my IBP/SocialLinks/etc/config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <global>
         <!-- ... -->
        <helpers>
            <ibp_sociallinks>
                <class>IBP_SocialLinks_Helper</class>
            </ibp_sociallinks>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

And here is the code of my IBP/SocialLinks/Helper/IBP_SocialLinks_Helper_Data.php

```
<?php
class IBP_SocialLinks_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

PS :

This command : **php -f shell/compiler.php -- state** gives me

```
Compiler Status:          Disabled
Compilation State:        Not Compiled
Collected Files Count:    0
Compiled Scopes Count:    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `IBP_SocialLinks_Helper_Data.php` to `Data.php`. The class name reflects the path below `app/code/{core,community,local}/`, not the file name (with `_` as pseudo namespace separator that translates to `/`)

Comment: Thanks I understand how it works. I thinked by viewing tutorials that the name of the class should be the name of the file class...